# trying to build a complex calculator in python

Tags: python

```
def calc():
    import math

    num=float(raw_input("Enter a number"))
    func=raw_input("Enter a function")
    result=math.func(num)
    return result

a=calc()
print a
```

I'm getting a number (num) and a name of a math function(func),(like: log,sqrt,sin,cos and such..)
I need to return the result of using this function on the number.

This is the Error i'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/try of 3", line 11, in <module>
    a=calc()
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/try of 3", line 8, in calc
    result=math.func(num)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func'
```

please help! how do I fix it?

Comment: `raw_input()` gets you a string but `log()` or `sqrt()` are functions. You gotta try other way.

Answer (score 3):

`math.func` means "get attribute named `"func"` from the object `math` (which does not have it). If you want to get an attribute by its dynamically calculated name, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
result = getattr(math, func)(num)
```

Or, more safe:

```
func = getattr(math, funcname, None)
if func:
    return func(arg)
else:
    ... # unknown function, report error
```

I'd consider also keeping a custom dictionary of the functions:

```
all_funcs = {'sin': math.sin,
             'cos': math.cos,
             'hex': hex}
...

func = all_funcs.get(funcname, None)
if func:
    return func(arg)
else:
    ... # unknown function, report error
```

That way you can more easily extend your functionality beyond what standard `math` has to offer.

Comment: Upvote for the elegant solution. The dictionary allows the program to simultaneously offer functions from different modules ni an easy way, decouples the functionality from the source (you can replace equivalent functions without affecting the interface) and let's you decide the name your function will take!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do this:

```
result = math.func(...)
```

You're not using your variable `func`, you referring to the name `math.func`, which clearly doesn't exist. To do what (I think) you're intending, you have to look up the function by it's name:

```
actual_func = getattr(math, func)
result = actual_func(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getattr`.

```
# place your import outside def
import math


def calc():

    num=float(raw_input("Enter a number"))
    func=raw_input("Enter a function")
    funcToCall = getattr(math, func)
    result=funcToCall(num)
    return result

a=calc()
print a
```

Comment: Maybe they down-voted you for putting an `import` statement inside a function. If you fix that, I'll upvote you...

Comment: fair enough, i was trying to point out what OP missed. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: thanks @PM2Ring for pointing out the `import` part. obviously I wasn't paying enough attention to the code

Comment: No worries, Anzel, I realise you were just doing a minimal change to the code in the OP. Maybe I've lived a sheltered life, but I'd never seen `import` used inside a normal function before I joined Stackoverflow. But here it seems that every second newbie is doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works too. Use the `if`/`elif` statement as shown below for each function you want to call. For example I have written only for `sqrt()`. Do the same for other functions and write in `elif` statement.

```
def calc():
    import math

    num=float(raw_input("Enter a number"))
    func=raw_input("Enter a function")
    if func.lower() == "sqrt":
        result=math.sqrt(num)
    return result

a=calc()
print a
```

Comment: This requires adding an `elif` for *every function you want to use from `math`*. At the very least, a dictionary lookup is more Pythonic: `{'sqrt': math.sqrt, ...}`.

Comment: Yes! I totally agree! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

def calc():

    num=float(raw_input("Enter a number"))
    func=raw_input("Enter a function")

    math_function = getattr(math, func, None)
    if not math_function:
        raise RuntimeError('Math func not found')
    return math_function(num)

print calc()
```

Comment: I don't think it deserves a downvote, but why raise an exception when you can print a friendly error message? And instead of raising a generic RuntimeError, it'd be better to put your `getattr()` call in a `try... except AttributeError` block.

Answer (score -2):

There is no gunction called `func` in math module.
I think you want to do this, but i'm not really sure.

```
return (num, func)
```